# My CardView doens't fit properly my GridLayout

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

i develope an application for a school project and now i'm doing the interface with andoid studio.

I'm using CardView and GridLayout to set up an nice interface but it doesn't fit properly to my screen.

**Here is my render :**

[image]

**But here is what i obtain when i'm running app :**

[image]

I don't understand what happen, here is my xml, i hope you could help me :

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"

    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

    android:padding="42dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_goto_joueur"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/footballplayer" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Joueurs"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_goto_equipe"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/americanfootball" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Equipes"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_goto_strategie"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/strategy" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stratégies"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_goto_celebration"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/celeb" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Célébrations"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_goto_tournoi"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/cup" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tournois"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_quit"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/quit" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quitter"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: first of all i recommend to use adapter instead of this static code, second thing: every CardView should has 0dp width and weight value =1

Comment: @AbuQauod i tried with all width at 0dp but the CardView isn't display and all weight value has already set at 1. What do you mean by adapter ? It's my first project with android, i'm still learning.

Comment: You have to read more cuz i  think its not easy for the first time, check this as example https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: okay thanks for your help, that work perfectly now and i learned new thing haha. thank you so much